# You can't open xcode because it is not supported on that Architecture?

Tags: macos, xcode5, vmware

I have install VMWARE (virtual Machine) on Windows 7. And have installed Mac OS Leopard 10.5.5 image on that Virtual Machine.
Now i want to install Xcode 5.1.1 on that Mac os, but it gives above Error. Please help me how and which version to install on that Mac OS Leopard 10.5.5.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 5.1 requires OS X 10.8 or 10.9. Xcode 3.1.4 is the latest version that runs on Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

When i was programming with xcode with vmware i didn`t managed to download it from the store and make it run in vmware, what i did is i downloaded a Mac OS with preinstalled xcode in it.

Also see the vmware options!

Comment: how to download Mac Os with preinstalled Xcode? please help and also tell me which version should i installed on Mac OS Leopard 10.5.5

Comment: You try to install it from store? or did you download it from a torrent? search for a vmware image containing Xcode or an image that you can install Xcode from store.(See that users tell in the comments)

Comment: i have downloaded it from store on windows. and then i copy it to Vmware Mac Os.